# Retrofit URL with query param

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2

I'm trying to use retrofit for the first time and missing simple logic..Please do help me with this issue.

This is my users class

```
public class User {

    private String name, email, password;

    public User(){
    }

    public User(String name, String email, String password){
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

API Interface

```
   public interface MyApiEndpointInterface {
        // Request method and URL specified in the annotation
        // Callback for the parsed response is the last parameter

        @GET("users?email={email}")
        Call<User> getUser(@Query("email") String email);
     }
```

This is how I get the details:

```
 public void getUserDetails()
{
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString()
    Call<User> call = apiService.getUser(email);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User>call, Response<User> response) {
            if(response.body()!=null)
            {
                Log.d("TAG", "Name: " + response.body().getName());
                Log.d("TAG", "Password: " + response.body().getPassword());
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "User does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAG", "User details does not exist");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User>call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("TAG", t.toString());
        }
    });
}
```

Now my issue is I have web api which is hosted on server and it looks like:

http://www.somesite.com

To get user details based on email provided I'm trying to use this:

http://www.somesite.com/api/user?email={email}

Now how do I set this url in api interface as its returning null ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `apiService` you should be creating a `Retrofit` object with the Builder and with this creating an instance of your `MyApiEndpointInterface` interface. There you add the baseUrl of the API.

It should looks something like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://yourapibaseUrl.com/api/")
                .build();

MyApiEndpointInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(MyApiEndpointInterface.class);
```

`apiInterface` is the object you will use for the calls to the API using Refit and it will already have set the baseUrl.

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Ah silly...Just now I too seen it as it was missing...Thanks buddy :)